# Access query to populate form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I would like to populate my form by looking up 2 fields and returning the total. Can this be done using expressions builder using Iif, and how do I set it?

ID (Query) = ID (Form)
Account 1 (Query) = Account A (Form) etc.

E.g. ID 123 will return **99** (55 + 44) in Form

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhjuc.png)

Comment: It looks like your form is just presenting a total for a given ID and Account Name combination. As a start, write your query to perform a GROUP BY on ID and Account Name and 'SUM' on Amount. Also, for future clarity, please take notice of calling something 'Account 1' in one place, then 'Account A' in another - it may lead to someone misunderstanding and giving you an incorrect answer.

Comment: Thanks Wayne. Actually the Account 1 and Account A are intended - they are different names for the same account (legacy data..). Does that change anything?

Comment: That won't change anything Wayne is suggesting. He is right, but he will not be notified of your comment. I suggest reviewing [replying in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). While you are at it, it's highly recommended to read over [tour] and [ask] to get you acclimated to the site. Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: In your example for your query, you show ID = 123, Acct = Account 1, and one row has 55 and the other has 44. You say you want *something* to result in a total of 99. Please explain exactly which two rows are being used to get your row on the form for ID = 123, Acct = 'Account 1' and total = 99. You must have a crossreference table or key to map Account 1 to Account A? Anyway, you can use a query to SUM the values.